# Read from a file,split it and store it in variables

Tags: string, python-3.x

I have a file which has data like this :

2905 5.0 10

1420 5.0 2

3011 5.0 2

659 5.0 2

121 5.0 1

1743 5.0 1

2056 5.0 1

2063 5.0 1

2185 5.0 1

2192 5.0 1

2198 5.0 1

2215 5.0 1

2562 5.0 1

2632 5.0 1

2675 5.0 1

2994 5.0 1

3038 5.0 1

3205 5.0 1

3245 5.0 1

3280 5.0 1

```
    f=open('/home/bhoots21304/Desktop/out12.txt','r')
    for line in f:
        a = line.strip().split('\t')
        (movieId, rating, views) = a
```

&& this code is throwing me an error:

```
(movieId, rating, views) = a

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Is there any other way to read from file, split the string and store it in some variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your splitting the string with `\t` which stand for tab. In your example, there isn't any tabs your values are separated by a space . This should work:

```
f=open('/home/bhoots21304/Desktop/out12.txt') #No need to use 'r', the default is 'r'
for line in f:
    if not line.strip(): continue #check to see if it's empty
    movieId, rating, views = line.strip().split(' ') #change it to a space
    #do stuff with them....
```

opening files is preferred using the `with` statement because it automatically closes the file for you when your program exits:

```
with open('/home/bhoots21304/Desktop/out12.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip(): continue #check to see if it's empty
        movieId, rating, views = line.strip().split(' ') #change it to a space
        #do stuff with them....
```

Comment: In your answer there are two problems.  First, there is a possible improvement `s/split(' ')/split()/` as `.split()` (no arguments) splits on generic white space, and that might be a better solution.  Second, more important, you have a factual error, as you said that the context manager "... automatically closes the file for you when your program exits"; on the contrary the file is closed as soon as program flow exits the `with` block.